# handle queue:work using exec in test mode - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, phpunit, laravel-artisan

I am having trouble externally processing jobs on the queue while in test mode using PHPUnit. I have a job that writes a message to the the log file which is dispatched when I visit a route, I thought it could work like the way it does in development where there is a terminal window listening for work with `php artisan queue:work` and the other running server.

Test.php

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $message = "Sample message job " . date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
    $filename = "laravel.log";
    $this->json('GET', route('test.test-try-log-job'), ['message' => $message]);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('jobs', [
        'id' => 1,
    ]);

    exec('php artisan queue:work');  // Artisan::call("queue:work");

}
```

Controller

```php
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function tryLogJob(Request $request){
        dispatch(new TestJob($request->message))->onQueue('default');
        return response()->json(['success'=>true], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Job

```php
class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    public $message;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info($this->message);
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

when I use `Artisan::call("queue:work");` the job is processed but when I use `exec('php artisan queue:work');`, it is not processed.

Is there a way I can get this to work? I really need to use the `exec()` function.

Comment: To run any queue in testing mode, you have to set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync`, so the queue is synchronous (instantly executed when something is dispatched). Do that in your `phpunit.xml`. If you check the default [`phpunit.xml`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/56a73db2e34f5aa8befffcce40aaaa92e2d7393c/phpunit.xml#L27) that Github gives you, it is already set, did you change it?

Comment: "When I do it properly it works fine, but I really need to do it the wrong way..." ???

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes I changed it to fit a usecase where the connection is database. I finally got it to work, sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phpunit.xml was configured to SQLite but the `.env` file was configured to MySQL.

During the test the job was being added to SQLite and not MySQL on which `exec('php artisan queue:work');` is run.

I set the database variables in phpunit.xml to match those .env (MySQL) and the jobs are being handled correctly.

Comment: You should use `.env.testing`

Comment: Let me read about it, thanks

Comment: @Victordanny I would suggest to **NOT** use any real database for queues, just use `sync` as you do not have to run `php artisan queue:work`, you do not test like that. Can you explain a little bit why you must use it? Also, `phpunit.xml` is going to "replace" any `.env` it finds, you do not need to copy-paste the same value you have on `.env`, you just need to add the one you want to override, and also be aware you can use `<env` or `<server`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, I wanted to ensure that the jobs are dispatched and handled asynchronously in the test environment. 
I have changed ```<env``` to ```<server``` thanks