# run blocking artisan call in the background during tests - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan

I am writing tests that need to interact with the queue, the use case is shown below;

```
public function testTryLogJobIsAsync()
{
    // dispatch a job here

    Artisan::call("queue:work");

    // assert if job performed required task e.g check if a file is written to

}
```

The job is processed but the trouble is `Artisan::call("queue:work");` blocks the rest of the execution.

Is there a way to run it in the background or run it for like for some seconds and stop it such that the following statements can also be executed?

Comment: This is related to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578762/handle-queuework-using-exec-in-test-mode-laravel) and my comments will fix your issue there, hence fixing it here too. Either way, when you test, you do `$this->artisan()` not `Artisan::call`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/console-tests#introduction) explaining that.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, I was able to fix the issue in the previous post. For this question I chose the timeout option, I've shared my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the option to start and stop the artisan command during the test and on Windows OS I achieved it by;
changing from

```
Artisan::call("queue:work");
```

to

```
exec('"%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -c "timeout 5 php artisan queue:work"');
```